# Center title on ToolBar

Tags: android, layout, center, toolbar

I have a problem, I can't center my title in my Toolbar (@+id/toolbar_title). I tried to put a RelativeLayout, use layout_gravity: center but it doesn't work. I have added colors to distinguish the layout but I can't post pictures yet.

http://hpics.li/72b1cf7

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/primaryDark"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/primary">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/show_list_actualites"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_fleche_bas"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/loupe"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:background="@color/primaryDark"
                        />
                    <!--android:background="@android:color/transparent"-->

                  <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/loupe"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="12dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_rech"
                        android:rotation="270"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:background="@color/primaryDark"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/slide_news_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_slider_news_menu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/action_bar_background"
                    android:text="Item 1"/>


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/close_news_slide"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/grey_tranparent"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/action_bar_text</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/action_bar_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/action_bar_text</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: You are aware that the standard for toolbar is left aligned?  There is a reason it is hard to do what you are trying (which is not to design standards)

Comment: I wonder if I shouldn't use the basic title of the Toolbar I don't see?

Comment: What do you mean you don't see it? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setTitle%28int%29

Comment: I'm forced to use the title of the Toolbar for it to be center ? With the title I added I don't use getSupportActionBar () setTitle (mTitle). Just : Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        TextView tle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        tle.setText(title);

Comment: No, you are missing the point, Toolbar title should NOT be centered, so you should use the Toolbar and NOT center your text.  This is hard for you because you shouldn't be doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Centering the Text in the Toolbar is against Android design standards.  I think this is why you are having issues accomplishing this.  I would not try to adjust your text alignment, which will insure your app fits within the Android ecosystem.

Check this link for details on Toolbar design standards: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-toolbars

I am not answering how you WOULD do what you are asking, but suggesting that you DON'T do it in the first place (use the standard format, and this will be easier for you).

Comment: This answer shouldn't be down voted.  Check those Material specs closely, and it will confirm that what I am saying is accurate - you SHOULDN'T do this (per the standards)

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

Toolbar's parent is **viewgroup**. So u cannot design like that. I used FrameLayout to place items.

```
               <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/primary">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/show_list_actualites"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/loupe"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:background="@color/primaryDark"
                        />
                    <!--     android:background="@android:color/transparent"-->

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/loupe"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="12dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:rotation="270"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:background="@color/primaryDark"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/primaryDark"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:text="Title"
                        />

                </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Really weird, the RelativeLayout does not occupy the entire toolbar despite match_parent : http://hpics.li/82e8ac3